# What BEST to use in .NET Form Application , DLL OR EXE?

Tags: .net, dll, exe

I'm developing  a .NET WINDOWS FORM Application , I need to develop a **search module**   and this search could be used in many other applications,

i'm wondering what is best to to Develeop Search as :

**DLL** and include it in the Application

OR

**EXE** file and execute it from other applications

what is the Advantages and Disadvantages for each way????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with putting the form in a class library and then adding it as a reference to all the projects I need it. Shelling out and executing it in a separate executable sounds messy. You also lose the ability to interact with the form object.

Answer (score 1):

If the search module is going to be used in many application, I recommend that you create it as a DLL (Class Library) and use it from the applications.

**Advantages :**

- It's easier to reuse code
- You don't have to track multiple versions of the search module if it's going to be updated/maintained in the future (You deploy only the DLL)
- You can easily get another developer to work on this feature while you work on something else.

**Disadvantages:**

- It's a pain switching projects in VS, especially if you already have many in the same solution

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is preferred to use a DLL and add it to your project as reference. Some advantages are:

1. You can reuse the classes, you don't have to implement some kind of inter-process communication
2. Starting a new application costs a lot of time as compared to instantiating a new class